# How To Change The Path of Products and Category in OpenCart?

Tags: php, url-routing, opencart

I want to change the the root path of OpenCart products, one level up from the index page. By default, a product page can be access by the following paths **(OpenCart Installed in Root)**;

1. domain.tld/product
2. domain.tld/category/sub-category/product
3. domain.tld/brands/brand-name/product

How can we move the path one page up or one level up from the root domain or index page?

So, for example;

1. hxxp://mydomain.com/**custom-page**/product-page
2. hxxp://mydomain.com/**custom-page**/category/sub-category/product-page
3. hxxp://mydomain.com/**custom-page**/brands/brand-name/product-page

I've already prepared the custom page with a path http://mydomain.tld/store
Latest modules, Specials and other modules was already installed to this page.

In my root, is a custom home page with a custom header that does not include the default OC menu, cart, search, wish list, and etc. It's an empty page, but having the default OC footer. My plan for this home page, is to put custom html, with some parallax effect. I am separating my STORE PAGE from this HOME PAGE.

I searched for similar threads from the official OC Forum, I found [similar post](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=114511&p=455510&hilit=change%20path#p455510) but it's not answered.

I want to achieve this, because I am preparing for a Wordpress Integration, which shall be accessible via domain.tld/blog

So my site navigtion would be,

mysite.tld/store
mysite.tld/blog

What could be the necessary files and code to edit if this is possible to achieve?

### **UPDATE**

I've tested Seo URL rewrites and rewrote ?route=product/* to /store. And I see good results. The bad side is, as shadyx mentioned, it's a lot of effort.

Also, after doing all the redirects/rewrites, I need again to deal with the breadcrumbs trails. So I also need to update it to mydomain.tld/store/category/sub-category/product. I don't have yet the solution for this.

*I guess, it's more easier to just install OC to /store folder.*

Comment: Hmm, in this case I would go for some simple CMS for the root (homepage) and install the whole OpenCart under the subdirectory (e.g. `custom-page`)... Though all the functionality will be moved now under this `custom-page`, but it has less effort. I.e., if You would like to proceed with what are You requesting, You would have to create (copy) catgories, products and manufacturers as a whole new *sub-module* called `custom-page`... And this woould mean both duplicate code and much more effort...

Comment: I also did that already, static html in root and O

Comment: I also did that already, static html in root and OC in /store folder, But I want my OC Header and Footer to be site-wide. That is why I want to stick with OpenCart so I can display and maintain my header, footer,in all parts of the site. I've also tried Wordpress in root, then blog site is on /blog using permalinks and custom index.php for the home page via child theme and then OC in /store. It's alright even it requires too much effort, so long as I can complete the requirement. I am also thinking by using htaccess rewrites.

Comment: Rewrites may do that as well, but You would have to edit every single part of the frontend that is creating links to products, categories, manufacturers, etc., to include this `custom-page` in the link...

Comment: I've just tried it, it's a lot of effort. Plus I am not a PHP developer, I'm just depending on research and readings. But I understand a bit about htaccess/mod_rewrite. Searching for aid again on how to modify the breadcrumbs trail/path.

Comment: As to the breadcrumbs, they are created in array, first item is `home`, then it follows Your path... Id suggest adding the `custom-page` to the `home` route in breadcrumbs, thus instead of `/` the home route will lead to `/custom-page/` (but I'm not sure what shall You display on that page). IMHO, this request is totally unnecessary and useless... You should rather focus on how to make Your shop better, not on such a useless URL rewrite...

Comment: Useless as you may think, But this is just my preparation to a bigger improvement to make my store better. Part of SEO, I'm not so good about web dev technicalities, but I'm confident with my SEO Skills.

Comment: Well, do not want to argue, but I see no SEO improvement here... Honestly, SEO is overused, overspoken, and for e-shops almost useless today, as customers are visiting e-shops more and more often via *price comparing portals/explorers*... And even if You use Google/Yahoo for searching for Your favourite product, most of the first results are links to these *price comparing portals*... Default SEO in OC is not perfect but is completely enough unless You are going to sell 100.000 of products and have plans to be the giant in e-commerce. But in this case OC is not the right choice at all...

Comment: Yeah I knew about those, That's why I've mentioned that I am confident with my SEO skills. Cause I know how to handle that. I even use those _price comparing portals/explorers_ to my SEO Advantage. I am also a Magento user, and it's best for scalability. And please don't consider our discussion as Arguments, 'coz these are our opinions and it's good for the community. ;-)

Comment: What a pitty one cannot contact other user directly, because I am really curious why a *Magento user* is also trying OpenCart. And I would also like to know whether You are *only a Magento user* or *Magento user and administrator* or *Magento developer*...